# Difference between **ptr and &ptr

Tags: c, pointers

According to my knowledge

`**ptr` = the address of memory location of the pointer variable ptr
`&ptr` =  the address of memory location where the value of ptr is stored.

Am I correct or `**ptr == &ptr`?

If they are equal whether I can pass `&ptr` as a pass by address for a function as a replacement to `ptr`? Knowledge me on this.

Comment: Could you please be more specific to your question? It is not clear enough.

Comment: If **ptr not same as &ptr  then second part is ruled out .R u clear Mr.haccks

Comment: `Am i correct or **ptr == &ptr` Obviously not, as already answered and accepted. Yet I am confused by what the quoted `**ptr = the address of memory location the pointer variable ptr itself` even means. It's either a terrible - and beyond wrong - automatic translation, or you are quoting from a terrible source that you shouldn't be using to learn C to begin with.

Comment: P.S. I see that you just edited the question and changed that to `**ptr = the address of memory location of the pointer variable ptr`. This makes it more parseable, but not any less wrong. Whoever gave you the idea to even ask this question is not to be trusted in C matters, whether it's an individual, or a blog, or a book.

Comment: `**ptr = the address of memory location of the pointer variable ptr` this what i wanted to tell. Since this is by my knowledge i have not posted from any other source ...Thanks for making me correct if I made  correct @dxiv

Comment: @skanda93 If it's your own knowledge, then don't quote it. (`>` begins a blockquote in Markdown.)

Comment: Ty @zenith i dint know about that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my knowledge on double pointer was wrong .

**ptr - Value of the variable pointed by another pointer or we can say it is a pointer to a pointer

let me clarify with an ex

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int num = 100 , *p , **ptr2ptr ;//Address of num=2000 ,p=3000 ,ptr2ptr=4000
p = &num;
ptr2ptr = &p;

printf("Single pointer *p =%d\n",*p);
printf("Double pointer **ptr2ptr=%d \n", **ptr2ptr);
printf("Address stored in p variable =%d \n", p);
printf("Address of p variable=%d\n", &p);
printf("Address of ptr2ptr=%d", &ptr2ptr);

return(0);
}
```

Output

```
Single pointer *p = 100
Double pointer **ptr2ptr= 100
Address stored in p variable =2000
Address of p variable=3000
Address of ptr2ptr=4000
```

From the above example it is clear **ptr2ptr(100) not equal to &ptr2ptr(4000) .

So I have found answer for my question .

Answer (score 5):

It might help if you understand that for any pointer (or array) `p` and index `i` the expression `*(p + i)` is equivalent to `p[i]`.

Now if `i` is zero that means we have `*(p + 0)` which is equal to `*p`, and its equivalent expression `p[0]`. That means when you do dereference a pointer you get the value of where it points.

Double-dereferencing a pointer only works if the pointer is pointing to another pointer.

You understanding of the address-of operator `&` is correct though.

---

Lets work on an example:

```
int a = 10;
int *p = &a;    // Makes p point to the variable a
int **pp = &p;  // Makes pp point to the variable p
```

Now if we do `*pp` we get the pointer `p`, and if we to `**pp` we get the variable `a` and its value.

```
printf("Value of a is %d\n", a);   // Will print "Value of a is 10\n"
printf("Value of *p is %d\n", *p);   // Will print "Value of *p is 10\n"
printf("Value of **pp is %d\n", **pp);   // Will print "Value of **pp is 10\n"
```

Also, using pointer to pointer might seem not very usable, but if you think about dynamically allocated arrays things change. For a dynamically allocated array you need to use a pointer, and if you want a matrix (i.e. an array of arrays) you need to use pointer to pointer, if you want to allocate both "dimensions" dynamically.

Furthermore, while C doesn't support passing arguments by reference, it can be emulated using pointers, and if you need to pass a pointer by reference you do it by passing a pointer to a pointer (using the address-of operator).

Lastly a small fun fact. I started this answer by telling you that `*(p + i)` and `p[i]` are equivalent. Because of the [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) property of addition, the expression `*(p + i)` is equivalent to `*(i + p)` which means that `p[i]` is equivalent to `i[p]`. Don't do it in real code though, it will only obfuscate the code and cause confusion for new readers of the code.

Comment: >      _You understanding of the address-of operator is correct though_.     Actually it was wrong

Comment: @skanda93 The expression `&ptr` is indeed "the address of memory location where the value of `ptr` is stored"

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the context: There is a difference when declaring and when using the pointer. In general, `&` is taking the address and `**` is dereferencing the pointer twice. Obviously, these are not the same.

But in variable decfinitions, `**` declares a pointer to a pointer. The declared variable can the take the address of a pointer as value:

```
int d = 10;
int *p = &d;
int **pp = &p;
```

This still doesn't mean that `**p` and `&` are the same: Here, the `**` is part of the variable's type: pointer to pointer to `int`.

The same applies to function argumets: The function

```
void f(int **p);
```

takes a pointer to pointer to `int` as argument and you can pass it the address of a pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

'*' operator is used to hold a memory address.

'&' operator returns the address at which the variable is held.

```
for example
int a = 10; (10 is located in memory at, for example, 0xddffff0
int *b = &a; (&a is the same thing as 0xddffff0, so b now points to that address)
```

So '&' operator returns the address while '*' operator point at the address.